# Regex for a proper closure of checkstyle

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to create a regex, that will check for proper 'closure' of a checkstyle (which begins with //)?

```
// CHECKSTYLE:OFF
protected void doSomething() {

}
// CHECKSTYLE:ON

// CHECKSTYLE:OFF
protected void doSomethingElse() {
// CHECKSTYLE:ON
}
```

If there is a typo in the first CHECKSTYLE:ON, the rest of checkstyles will be ignored.

Comment: My feeling here is that you really need a parser, not a regex.  What is your expected output from what you have in mind here?

Comment: I have an IntelliJ plugin called CheckStyle-IDEA and I want to write a proper <module> for catching 'unclosed' CHECKSTYLE tags

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if a pure regex would be appropriate here.  Your problem is the really the stuff with which parsers are concerned.  Actually, I don't even know how we would detect `// CHECKSTYLE:ON` with a typo in it.  But, one option here would be to simply scan your file line by line, and fail if we ever encounter two `// CHECKSTYLE:OFF` in a row.  If that happens, then it implies that either the ON checkstyle was completely omitted, or it was mispelled.

```
static final String CHECK_ON = "// CHECKSTYLE:ON";
static final String CHECK_OFF = "// CHECKSTYLE:OFF";

File file = new File("your_input.ext");
boolean checkstyleIsOn = false;

try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    int lineNum = 0;

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        ++lineNum;
        String line = sc.nextLine();

        if (CHECK_OFF.equals(line)( {
            if (!checkStyleIsOn) {
                System.out.println("Found extra checkstyle off at line " + lineNum);
                break;
            }
            else {
                checkStyleIsOn = false;
            }
        }
        if (CHECK_ON.equals(line)( {
            if (checkStyleIsOn) {
                System.out.println("Found extra checkstyle on at line " + lineNum);
                break;
            }
            else {
                checkStyleIsOn = true;
            }
        }

    }
    sc.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```